# How to extract the values from the dictionary with condition

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary is below, if the values end with `csv` or `json` i need to put in another dictionary of same dictionary:

```
d = {'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}
```

Code is below:

```
d = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        if i.split('.')[1] == 'csv' or i.split('.')[1] == 'json':
            d[k] = v
```

My out

```
{'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}
```

Expected out

```
{'a': ['1.json', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.csv']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change v, so the dictionary is unchanged. You should build a new list only keeping the wanted values:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    v = [i for i in v if i.split('.')[1] in ('csv', 'json')]
    d[k] = v
```

or even better:

```
d = {k: [i for i in v if i.split('.')[1] in ('csv', 'json')]
     for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dict comprehension* with *list comp* on each of the values while filtering with [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

```
d = {'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}

new = {k:[i for i in v if i.endswith(('.csv','.json'))] for k,v in d.items()}
# {'a': ['1.json', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.csv']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use rfind to find the last . in the file name and to add it the list if it's matching CSV or JSON

```
d = {'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}
for k, v in d.items():
  d[k] = []
  for i in v:
    if i[i.rfind(".") + 1:] in ('csv', 'json'):
        d[k].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(list)
d = {'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}

for k, v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        if i.split('.')[-1] in ['csv', 'json']:
            x[k].append(i)

print(dict(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be the following, assuming you want to update the existing dictionary

```py
for k, v in d.items():
  for i in v:
    if i.rsplit('.')[-1] not in {'csv','json'}:
       v.remove(i)
```

Comment: A bit better to use `set` instead of `list`. Also `i.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` will be sligthly faster. And you should avoid modifying list while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split filename and add condition for checking the file type (using list for comparison could be a better option if you want to add more file types).

Combine this with list Comprehension, which provides a concise way to create lists.

```
d = {'a': ['1.json', '1.html', '1.csv'], 'B': ['2.json', '2.html', '2.csv']}

filtered_d = {key:[item for item in value if item.split('.')[-1] in ['json','csv']] for key, value in d.items()}
```

you can check documentation here for more detail on [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).